# Awk concise way to check if 2 fields match the same string

Tags: awk

I want check if 2 fields match a specific pattern, this is what I have so far:

`openstack floating ip list -f value | awk '$3 ~ /None/ && $4 ~ /None/{print $2}'`

It prints the second field if the 3rd and 4rd field equal "None" which is what i want, but it seems inefficient.

Is there a more concise way to do this with `awk`?

Comment: If you want the fields to match exactly, then you should use `$3 == "None"`. Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Comment: Why are you concerned about making the code more concise?  It is concise as it stands.  I suppose you could eliminate the spacing, but that merely makes it harder to read rather than any more concise.  Your script is only 30-odd characters; it isn't worth worrying about (other than the equality vs regex change mooted in comment and answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for equality you should use the `==` (or `!=`) operator which is more efficient because it doesn't need to perform a regular expression match:

```
awk '$3 == "None" && $4 == "None" {print $2}'
```

The rest looks good.

Comment: Would this be a working alternative? `'$3==$4!="None" {print $2}'`

Comment: @George no, it wouldn't.

Comment: `awk '$3==$4 && $4=="None"'`

Comment: @karakfa, thats a really nice awk golfing, works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
awk '$3$4~/None{2}/{print $2}'
```

but that would produce a false match if $3 contained "NoneNone" and $4 was empty, etc. so YMMV wrt what you data actually contains. You could tweak it to:

```
awk '$3" "$4" " ~ /(None ){2}/{print $2}'
```

but it's getting kinda obscure now. The only sensible way to improve your script is to just not use the same hard-coded value multiple times:

```
awk -v n="None" '$3==n && $4==n{print $2}'
```